# ng-table filter millisecond date data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

My date data comes from JSON in milliseconds. I have filtered it in view using `{{date | date:Filter}}`, but filter doesn't work. When I am writing in input filter field it actually works on milliseconds data.
How to make filter working on already filtered view data?

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10,
    sorting: {
        creationDate: 'desc'
    }
}, {
    counts: [],
    total: $scope.pagainationRslt.length, 
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
            // use build-in angular filter
            var filteredData = params.filter() ?
            $filter('filter')($scope.pagainationRslt, params.filter()) :
            $scope.pagainationRslt;
            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
            $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                $scope.pagainationRslt;

            params.count($scope.currentCount)
            params.total(orderedData.length)
            $defer.resolve(orderedData);

    } 
});
```

and html:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true"class="ui collapsing celled striped table">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in $data">
    <td sortable="'date'" filter="{ 'date' : 'text' }">{{item.date | date:dateEUFormat}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you mean you get your data from JSON as nanoseconds and the filter only works on millis?

Comment: I get my data like this: 1455099722667. I want to filter is like how it is in the view for example like this: 10-Feb-2016 12:22. When I type in filter it respond to milliseconds not to view format.

Answer (score 0):

For your date formatting, add the right format string, something like this:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true"class="ui collapsing celled striped table">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in $data">
    <td sortable="'date'" filter="{ 'date' : 'text' }">{{item.date | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm'}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a full example: https://jsbin.com/xetonidina/edit?html,js,output

I am still unsure if your dates are in the wrong format, ie. 1455235722 instead of 1455235722667. If that's the problem:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true"class="ui collapsing celled striped table">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in $data">
    <td sortable="'date'" filter="{ 'date' : 'text' }">{{(item.date * 1000) | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm'}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: My dates are proper format. In webview are also proper. The problem is when I use filter it filters the back data. For example: if that is the date 1455235722667 and in web view is 19-02-2016 12:12 when I type integer "3" it takes 14552"3"5722667, and this is complete wrong

Comment: Where do you type anything?

Comment: In ng-table input field filter

Comment: OK, it would have been really nice if you had written down your whole use case. Now my answer is worthless.